# random html link selector from group of links

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink

random html link selector from group of links.

so i have this image on my site, when clicked it takes you to a html page. that's good, only thing is i want it to randomly select a link from a group of lets say five links, not just 1 html link.

```
<a href="url" target="_blank"><img id="img-hover" src="image"/></a>
```

i need the function of the code above still to work. so please incorporate your code with mine. sorry for english. also, this code goes off of some java but i don't think you need it. but here it is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer;

document.getElementById('img-hover').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
var elem = this;
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.src='image';
}, 9000);
});

document.getElementById('img-hover').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
var elem = this;
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.src='image?v=513d43d2';
}, 9999999999999999);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will need to be done using JavaScript. Create an array of URLs, and on the click of the image, generate a random number between `0` and `array.length - 1`, pick that index from the array, and redirect to it.

Comment: Do you have an array with the image sources or do you need the algorithm to pull the file names from the server? Generally you just need a random number function with the max amount of images you have available and a way for the script to assign an image source to the number.

Comment: Exactly what **Santi** said. I'm curious to why you have your second timeout set to `9999999999999999`...  The browser counting down from 9999999999999999? Are you expecting visitors to stay on that page that long?

Comment: it will? what happens is when you hover over the image for 10 seconds, it changes, i didn't want the second image to go away so that why it's so high... so if i put nothing it will stay forever/

Comment: Well on mouseover you will have 9 seconds before that first time out will run. The mousout event will change the src to `image?v=513d43d2` after 115740740 days

Comment: @NewToJS you should try and wait for it.......come back when it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, but replace the URL's with your own, of course.

```
<a href="#" onclick="randomUrl();" target="_blank"><img id="img-hover" src="image"/></a>
```

```
var urlArray = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.yahoo.com",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
];

function randomUrl() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
    var newUrl = urlArray[randomNumber];
    window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/ea60hg9L/)

Comment: would it be possible instead of typing each link out that it just picks one from the domain? my website's pretty big and i dont really want to paste everyone of them, and have to edit  the script when i add more pages.

Comment: That is a much bigger task than just randomly choosing a URL. I don't believe JavaScript can't read the contents of a folder, so unless you have distinctly sequenced pages (page1, page2, page3, page4) that you could create a pattern loop for, you'd need some sort of server-side element to resolve all URLs in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array with url locations

`var locations = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5];`

then you could say

`var url = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);`

This will generate a random number between 0 and 5

now you can find your a tag and modify the href to a random element of the array

`document.getElementById('img-hover').href = locations[url]`

Comment: so it would look like this? <a href=[url1, url2, url3, url4, url5]; target="_blank"><img id="img-hover" src="image"/></a>

Comment: Not necessarily, the code I gave you is all put in a script tag. Because you search ``document.getElementById('img-hover')`` you will select that a tag and set its href to 1 of the 5 urls in "locations". However, you have to still put in the urls data yourself... it shouldn't be ``var locations = [url1, url2,...]`` but ``var locations = ["www.google.com", "www.stackoverflow.com",...]``